# pass object to composable through deep link

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

first to validate passing string logic through through deep link I tried to pass static string to deep link using

```
 val planetaryJson= "text"
 navController.navigate("${Screen.PlanetaryDetails.route}/$planetaryJson")
```

and it worked fine

then I tried to convert object to string and then pass that string by

```
 val planetaryJson = moshi.adapter(Planetary::class.java).toJson(planetaryDetails)
 navController.navigate("${Screen.PlanetaryDetails.route}/$planetaryJson")
```

but it throw

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/planetaryDetails/{"serviceVersion":"v1","title":"Sunset, Shadowrise","explanation":"From central Australia, this serene 360 degree panorama follows a clear horizon as twilight began on May 28. At left, a bright western sky is still illuminated by the setting Sun. But sweeping right, toward a view centered on the countryside's dominating sandstone formation called Uluru or Ayers Rock, the sky takes on progressively darker hues and subtle colors. Behind Uluru is the shadow of planet Earth itself, a dark blue arch rising in the east. Cast through the dense atmosphere and still close to the horizon, Earth's long shadow is bounded above by a pinkish glow or antitwilight arch. Known as the Belt of Venus, the lovely color of the antitwilight arch is due to backscattering of reddened light from the setting Sun. On that night, a nearly full Moon also rose above Earth's shadow in the eastern sky.","date":"29/07/2010","mediaType":"image","hdUrl":"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1007/BeltOfVenusPan_ward.jpg","url":"https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1007/BeltOfVenusPan_ward600h.jpg","favourite":false} } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x8ed1d0ff) route=planetariesList}
> ```

here is my `PlanetaryDetails` fun

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.addPlanetariesDetails(
    navController: NavHostController,
    state: MutableState<PlanetaryListState>,
    events: (event: PlanetaryListEvent) -> Unit,
    imageLoader: ImageLoader
) {

    composable(
        route = Screen.PlanetaryDetails.route +"/{planetaryJson}" ,
    ) {

        // code here
    }
}
```

and here is `PlanetaryDetails` object in `Screen` class

```
object PlanetaryDetails: Screen(
    route = "planetaryDetails",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("planetaryJson"){
            type = NavType.StringType
        }
    )
)
```

though is it possible to pass a object as nav argument through deeplink or there is an issue

also I wanted to pass it this way to receive the argument in `viewmodel` by `savedStateHandle`

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the json?

Comment: @MatPag yes I have tried api resquest using this Moshi adapter and it succeeded